# How to hide button when another button is clicked in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button, show-hide

I have 2 buttons displayed on the page `Display` and `Hide`. When the `Hide` button is clicked I want to hide the `Display` button.

I am using `useState`. To some extent, I am `able to hide Display more text` present on the button, but not the whole button

Initial state- https://ibb.co/jMdH3tq

When the Hide button is clicked, Display text disappear but the button stays- https://ibb.co/Jm5FPNy

```
const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

const hideButton = () => {
  setShow(true);
};
```

Hide button code:

```
<div>
  <button
    style={{ marginLeft: '190px' }}
    className="button button1"
    onClick={() => {
      clearBooks();
      hideButton();
    }}
  >
    Hide
  </button>
</div>;
```

Show button code:

```
<button
  className="button button1"
  style={{ marginLeft: '190px', width: '124px', height: '50px' }}
  onClick={fetchBooks}
>
  {!show && 'Display more'}
</button>;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to hide the button do the following: I noticed the show state is set to false initially and you are setting it to true on click. Do you want the opposite, true as initial state hide when selecting the button?

Based on that, adjust show accordingly either show or !show

```
{show &&
<button
    className="button button1"
    style={{ marginLeft: "190px", width: "124px", height: "50px" }}
    onClick={fetchBooks}
  >
  </button> 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A tidier way of doing this would be to use the ternary operator with your state. Every time your buttons are clicked, they invert the state which changes which button is rendered in the DOM.

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(true);

  function changeState() {
    setShow(!show);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {show ? (
        <button onClick={changeState}> Display </button>
      ) : (
        <button onClick={changeState}> Hide </button>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I am not sure, this will work in my case. There are 2 things I am doing. When `Hide` button is clicked `Display` is set to hidden. I have another button `Show` button appears. Now when `Show ` is clicked, I again need to display `Display` button

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to re-render, you can achieve this by using classes as follows:

**screen.js**

```
import "./styles.css"

export default function MyScreen() {
  const onButtonPressed = (target) => {
    document.querySelector('button.hide').classList.remove('hide')
    target.classList.add('hide')
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <button
        style={{ marginLeft: 190 }}
        className="button button1 hide"
        onClick={(element) => {
          onButtonPressed(element.target)
          clearBooks()
        }}
      >
        {"Hide"}
      </button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button
        className="button button1"
        style={{ marginLeft: 190, width: 124, height: 50 }}
        onClick={(element) => {
          onButtonPressed(element.target)
          fetchBooks()
        }}
      >
        {"Display more"}
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

**styles.css**

```
button.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

This is an example testing the JS functionality:

```css
button.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <button
        class="button button1 hide"
        style="margin-left:190px;width:124px;height:50px"
        onClick="onButtonPressed(this)"
    >
        Hide
    </button>
</div>
<div>
    <button
        class="button button1"
        style="margin-left:190px;width:124px;height:50px"
        onClick="onButtonPressed(this)"
    >
        Display more
    </button>
</div>

<script>
    function onButtonPressed(element) {
        document.querySelector('button.hide').classList.remove('hide')
        element.classList.add('hide')
    }
</script>
```